# Получение сводной таблицы из двух sql

Tags: sql

Есть таблица products с товарами разных продавцов. У продавцов есть одинаковые товары. Но у каждого продавца свой id и название для этого товара. Для того чтобы понять, что товар по смыслу один и тот же есть вторая таблица connections, определяющая связь между товарами. Необходимо получить таблицу result, в которой будут соотнесенные данные о товарах. Как должен выглядеть запрос sql?[image: мм]

Comment: *Как должен выглядеть запрос sql?* Тут возможен только один ответ: запрос должен выглядеть некрасиво. Монстрообразно и нереляционно.

Comment: @Akina Это только через цикл решается, либо через рекурсию, видимо? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Зависит от СУБД. В общем случае - через динамический SQL. А вообще такой ерундой лучше пусть клиент занимается. К тому же структура хранения соответствий - оторвать и выбросить... петли получить как делать нечего.

Comment: @Akina, да, я вижу, что данное решение по соотношению товаров плохое, но не вижу пока как по другому их соотнести

Comment: *я вижу, что данное решение по соотношению товаров плохое, но не вижу пока как по другому их соотнести* Таблица зависимостей должна иметь два поля - номер группы связанных товаров и ИД товара этой группы. Соответственно для показанных данных там будет 6 записей - две группы, 1 и 2, в первой товары 1,3,5, во второй остальные. Кроме того, это даёт возможность включать товар в более чем одну группу... но тогда нужна ещё и таблица групп.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу таблиц: может, так сделать:
Таблица"Поставщики": idПоставщ, idТовар, Цена.
Таблица "Товары": idТовар, название, группа.
(группа - это просто"картофель", "морковь")

```
    SELECT название, группа,
    CASE WHEN idПоставщ=1
         THEN цена END AS 'ПоставщикА',
    CASE WHEN idПоставщ=2
         THEN цена END AS 'ПоставщикБ',
    CASE WHEN idПоставщ=3
         THEN цена END AS 'ПоставщикС'
    FROM Товары INNER JOIN Поставщики 
    ON Товары.idТовар= 
       Поставщики.idТовар;
```

[Про сводные таблицы с помощью sql][1]https://habr.com/ru/post/506070/